# Is it possible to change svg path height with css transform? (not scale, not whole svg, only one path)

Tags: css, animation, svg, transform, scale

I'm trying to increase the height of an SVG path (the border) and I'm getting the problem that the border gets hidden, only grows to down direction (not up) and the rounded corners get stretched. If I do the scale with the whole SVG also the icon inside get stretched and I want a uniform grow for that icon. I think using a div for that box is not a solution either because I would like the whole composition get resized to fill the space responsively.

Any solution?

```css
#box{
  position:absolute;
  left: 80px;
}
#t-shirt{
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top: 25%;
}
#t-shirt:hover {
  transform: scale(1,1.2);
}
#pants{
  position: absolute;
  left: 160px;
  top: 25%;
}
#pants:hover #pants-border{
  transform: scale(1,1.2);
}
```

```html
<svg id="box" width="315" height="341" viewBox="0 0 315 341" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect x="10.5" y="9.5" width="304" height="331" rx="19.5" fill="#242420" stroke="#242420"/>
<rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="304" height="331" rx="19.5" fill="#D9D9D9" stroke="#242420"/>
<circle cx="23" cy="20" r="6.5" fill="#C9C9C9" stroke="#242420"/>
<circle cx="47" cy="20" r="6.5" fill="#C9C9C9" stroke="#242420"/>
<circle cx="71" cy="20" r="6.5" fill="#C9C9C9" stroke="#242420"/>
</svg>

<svg id="t-shirt" width="147" height="147" viewBox="0 0 147 147" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path height="200" d="M19.3522 0.706462H126.757C137.178 0.706462 145.626 9.15414 145.626 19.5749V126.98C145.626 137.4 137.178 145.848 126.757 145.848H19.3522C8.93148 145.848 0.483806 137.4 0.483806 126.98V19.5749C0.483806 9.15414 8.93149 0.706462 19.3522 0.706462Z" fill="#EBEBEB" stroke="#242420" stroke-width="0.967611"/>
  <path d="M112.243 116.336H34.834L35.0547 113.12L35.2341 110.749L35.441 107.977L35.6066 105.579L35.8135 102.806L35.9928 100.408L36.1998 97.6353L36.3653 95.2648L41.1525 29.251H53.8172C53.9529 34.4014 56.0844 39.295 59.7577 42.8896C63.431 46.4841 68.3559 48.4956 73.4833 48.4956C78.6106 48.4956 83.5354 46.4841 87.2087 42.8896C90.882 39.295 93.0136 34.4014 93.1493 29.251H105.869L110.643 95.2648L110.822 97.6353L111.029 100.408L111.194 102.806L111.401 105.579L111.581 107.977L111.788 110.749L111.953 113.12L112.243 116.336Z" fill="#D9D9D9"/>
  <path d="M37.7369 29.251L13.5466 58.7078L34.2872 75.6963L37.7369 29.251Z" fill="#d9d9d9"/>
  <path d="M109.34 29.251L133.53 58.7078L112.776 75.6963L109.34 29.251Z" fill="#D9D9D9"/>
</svg>

<svg id="pants" width="148" height="147" viewBox="0 0 148 147" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path id="pants-border" d="M19.8137 0.706462H128.186C138.607 0.706462 147.055 9.15414 147.055 19.5749V126.98C147.055 137.4 138.607 145.848 128.186 145.848H19.8136C9.39288 145.848 0.945231 137.4 0.945231 126.98V19.5749C0.945231 9.15414 9.39291 0.706462 19.8137 0.706462Z" fill="#EBEBEB" stroke="#242420" stroke-width="0.967611"/>
<path d="M103.028 12.8018V19.575L74 19.5611V19.575H44.9717V12.8018H103.028Z" fill="#DADADA"/>
<path d="M94.3198 24.4131H103.028V33.1216C94.465 32.713 94.3198 24.4131 94.3198 24.4131Z" fill="#DADADA"/>
<path d="M103.028 38.4122V132.786H80.6181L74.021 45.4874L67.382 132.786H44.9717V38.4122C48.7254 37.779 57.6755 35.1361 57.6755 24.4131H71.5839C71.5839 31.7636 71.3738 38.1781 73.993 38.2607C76.6262 38.2607 76.4161 31.7636 76.4161 24.4131H90.3385C90.3245 35.1361 99.2746 37.779 103.028 38.4122Z" fill="#DADADA"/>
<path d="M44.9717 33.1216V24.4131H53.6802C53.6802 24.4131 53.5205 32.713 44.9717 33.1216Z" fill="#DADADA"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Have two paths, on hover swap to the other (larger) path by hiding one and displaying the other.

Comment: Your SVG `viewbox`es are the limiting factors. SVG won't draw outside that box, basically clipping the 'overflow'. Double the viewbox width/height values of `#pants` and see it work. 'Stretch' the box a bit for the max scale you need and you can scale any path individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [@n--](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74151265/is-it-possible-to-change-svg-path-height-with-css-transform-not-scale-not-who/74151562#74151562) you need to scale your elements separately on hover:

- rectangle background
- icon

To avoid **distortions**, you could use a `<rect>` element with `rx` `ry` attributes (for rounded borders) and change the `height` and `y` values on hover.

We can avoid **clipping** by applying a `overflow:visible` property to the svgs.

```css
svg {
  overflow: visible;
}

svg * {
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#box {
  position: absolute;
  left: 80px;
}

#t-shirt {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 25%;
}

#pants {
  position: absolute;
  left: 160px;
  top: 25%;
}


/* scale rect by changing height */

#t-shirt:hover .rect-shirt {
  height: 180px;
  y: -14px;
}


/* scale icons */

svg:hover .g-icon {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}


/* scale rect by changing d */

#pants:hover .rect-pants {
  d: path("M0 4.8 a 19.5 19.5 0 0 1 19.5-19.5 h 107 a 19.5 19.5 0 0 1 19.5 19.5 v 140 a19.5 19.5 0 0 1-19.5 19.5 h -107 a19.5 19.5 0 0 1-19.5-19.5 z");
}
```

```html
<svg id="box" width="315" height="341" viewBox="0 0 315 341" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect x="10.5" y="9.5" width="304" height="331" rx="19.5" fill="#242420" stroke="#242420" />
  <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="304" height="331" rx="19.5" fill="#D9D9D9" stroke="#242420" />
  <circle cx="23" cy="20" r="6.5" fill="#C9C9C9" stroke="#242420" />
  <circle cx="47" cy="20" r="6.5" fill="#C9C9C9" stroke="#242420" />
  <circle cx="71" cy="20" r="6.5" fill="#C9C9C9" stroke="#242420" />
</svg>

<svg id="t-shirt" width="147" height="147" viewBox="0 0 147 147" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect class="rect-shirt transition" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="146" height="146" rx="19.5" fill="#EBEBEB" stroke="#242420" stroke-width="1" ></rect>
  
  <g class="g-icon g-shirt">
  <path d="M112.243 116.336H34.834L35.0547 113.12L35.2341 110.749L35.441 107.977L35.6066 105.579L35.8135 102.806L35.9928 100.408L36.1998 97.6353L36.3653 95.2648L41.1525 29.251H53.8172C53.9529 34.4014 56.0844 39.295 59.7577 42.8896C63.431 46.4841 68.3559 48.4956 73.4833 48.4956C78.6106 48.4956 83.5354 46.4841 87.2087 42.8896C90.882 39.295 93.0136 34.4014 93.1493 29.251H105.869L110.643 95.2648L110.822 97.6353L111.029 100.408L111.194 102.806L111.401 105.579L111.581 107.977L111.788 110.749L111.953 113.12L112.243 116.336Z" fill="#D9D9D9" />
  <path d="M37.7369 29.251L13.5466 58.7078L34.2872 75.6963L37.7369 29.251Z" fill="#d9d9d9" />
  <path d="M109.34 29.251L133.53 58.7078L112.776 75.6963L109.34 29.251Z" fill="#D9D9D9" />
    </g>
</svg>

<svg id="pants" width="148" height="147" viewBox="0 0 148 147" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path class="rect-pants transition" fill="#EBEBEB" stroke="#242420" stroke-width="1" d="
M0 19.5
a19.5 19.5 0 0 1 19.5-19.5
h107
a19.5 19.5 0 0 1 19.5 19.5
v107a19.5 19.5 0 0 1-19.5 19.5
h-107
a19.5 19.5 0 0 1-19.5-19.5
z"/>
  
  <g class="g-icon g-pants">
  <path d="M103.028 12.8018V19.575L74 19.5611V19.575H44.9717V12.8018H103.028Z" fill="#DADADA" />
  <path d="M94.3198 24.4131H103.028V33.1216C94.465 32.713 94.3198 24.4131 94.3198 24.4131Z" fill="#DADADA" />
  <path d="M103.028 38.4122V132.786H80.6181L74.021 45.4874L67.382 132.786H44.9717V38.4122C48.7254 37.779 57.6755 35.1361 57.6755 24.4131H71.5839C71.5839 31.7636 71.3738 38.1781 73.993 38.2607C76.6262 38.2607 76.4161 31.7636 76.4161 24.4131H90.3385C90.3245 35.1361 99.2746 37.779 103.028 38.4122Z" fill="#DADADA" />
  <path d="M44.9717 33.1216V24.4131H53.6802C53.6802 24.4131 53.5205 32.713 44.9717 33.1216Z" fill="#DADADA" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

#### Alternative: transition the `d` (path data) attribute

The pants rectangle is drawn as a path using relative commands

```
M 0 19.5
a 19.5 19.5 0 0 1 19.5-19.5
h 107
a 19.5 19.5 0 0 1 19.5 19.5
v 107
a 19.5 19.5 0 0 1-19.5 19.5
h -107
a 19.5 19.5 0 0 1-19.5-19.5
z
```

The hovered `d` can be created by just changing the `M` y value and
the `v` (vertical line to) like so

```
M 0 4.8 // rectangle's x/y position 
a 19.5 19.5 0 0 1 19.5-19.5 
h 107 
a 19.5 19.5 0 0 1 19.5 19.5 
v 140 // rectangle's height
a 19.5 19.5 0 0 1-19.5 19.5 
h -107 
a 19.5 19.5 0 0 1-19.5-19.5 
z
```

We can change the paths geometry using the css [`path()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/path) method:

```
/* scale rect by changing d */
#pants:hover .rect-pants{
  d:path("M0 4.8 a 19.5 19.5 0 0 1 19.5-19.5 h 107 a 19.5 19.5 0 0 1 19.5 19.5 v 140 a19.5 19.5 0 0 1-19.5 19.5 h -107 a19.5 19.5 0 0 1-19.5-19.5 z");
}
```

Comment: That's awesom @herrstrietzel, exactly what I need!! Tanks you so much

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the desired result, then this can be done by using a [grouping element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g) for certain paths, then apply a [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/) with the `center` origin to it:

```css
#box {
  position:absolute;
  left: 80px;
}
#t-shirt, #pants {
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top: 25%;
}
#pants{
  left: 160px;
}
#t-shirt:hover,
#pants:hover {
  transform: scale(1,1.2);
}
#t-shirt:hover g,
#pants:hover g {
  transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
  transform-origin: center;
}
```

```html
<svg id="box" width="315" height="341" viewBox="0 0 315 341" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect x="10.5" y="9.5" width="304" height="331" rx="19.5" fill="#242420" stroke="#242420"/>
<rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="304" height="331" rx="19.5" fill="#D9D9D9" stroke="#242420"/>
<circle cx="23" cy="20" r="6.5" fill="#C9C9C9" stroke="#242420"/>
<circle cx="47" cy="20" r="6.5" fill="#C9C9C9" stroke="#242420"/>
<circle cx="71" cy="20" r="6.5" fill="#C9C9C9" stroke="#242420"/>
</svg>

<svg id="t-shirt" width="147" height="147" viewBox="0 0 147 147" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path height="200" d="M19.3522 0.706462H126.757C137.178 0.706462 145.626 9.15414 145.626 19.5749V126.98C145.626 137.4 137.178 145.848 126.757 145.848H19.3522C8.93148 145.848 0.483806 137.4 0.483806 126.98V19.5749C0.483806 9.15414 8.93149 0.706462 19.3522 0.706462Z" fill="#EBEBEB" stroke="#242420" stroke-width="0.967611"/>
  <g>
    <path d="M112.243 116.336H34.834L35.0547 113.12L35.2341 110.749L35.441 107.977L35.6066 105.579L35.8135 102.806L35.9928 100.408L36.1998 97.6353L36.3653 95.2648L41.1525 29.251H53.8172C53.9529 34.4014 56.0844 39.295 59.7577 42.8896C63.431 46.4841 68.3559 48.4956 73.4833 48.4956C78.6106 48.4956 83.5354 46.4841 87.2087 42.8896C90.882 39.295 93.0136 34.4014 93.1493 29.251H105.869L110.643 95.2648L110.822 97.6353L111.029 100.408L111.194 102.806L111.401 105.579L111.581 107.977L111.788 110.749L111.953 113.12L112.243 116.336Z" fill="#D9D9D9"/>
    <path d="M37.7369 29.251L13.5466 58.7078L34.2872 75.6963L37.7369 29.251Z" fill="#d9d9d9"/>
    <path d="M109.34 29.251L133.53 58.7078L112.776 75.6963L109.34 29.251Z" fill="#D9D9D9"/>
  </g>
</svg>

<svg id="pants" width="148" height="147" viewBox="0 0 148 147" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path id="pants-border" d="M19.8137 0.706462H128.186C138.607 0.706462 147.055 9.15414 147.055 19.5749V126.98C147.055 137.4 138.607 145.848 128.186 145.848H19.8136C9.39288 145.848 0.945231 137.4 0.945231 126.98V19.5749C0.945231 9.15414 9.39291 0.706462 19.8137 0.706462Z" fill="#EBEBEB" stroke="#242420" stroke-width="0.967611"/>
  <g>
    <path d="M103.028 12.8018V19.575L74 19.5611V19.575H44.9717V12.8018H103.028Z" fill="#DADADA"/>
    <path d="M94.3198 24.4131H103.028V33.1216C94.465 32.713 94.3198 24.4131 94.3198 24.4131Z" fill="#DADADA"/>
    <path d="M103.028 38.4122V132.786H80.6181L74.021 45.4874L67.382 132.786H44.9717V38.4122C48.7254 37.779 57.6755 35.1361 57.6755 24.4131H71.5839C71.5839 31.7636 71.3738 38.1781 73.993 38.2607C76.6262 38.2607 76.4161 31.7636 76.4161 24.4131H90.3385C90.3245 35.1361 99.2746 37.779 103.028 38.4122Z" fill="#DADADA"/>
    <path d="M44.9717 33.1216V24.4131H53.6802C53.6802 24.4131 53.5205 32.713 44.9717 33.1216Z" fill="#DADADA"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final result. Thanks again herrstrietzel!

```css
svg {
  overflow: visible;
}

svg * {
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#box {
  position: absolute;
  left: 80px;
}

#boots{
  position: absolute;
  left: 320px;
  top: 110px;
}

#t-shirt {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 110px;
}

#t-shirt .rect-shirt{
  animation: t-shirt-animation 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes t-shirt-animation {
  0%,20%{height: 147px; y: 0px;}
  25%,45%{height: 180px; y: -14px;}
  50%,100%{height: 147px; y: 0px;}
}

#t-shirt .g-icon{
  animation: t-shirt-icon-animation 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes t-shirt-icon-animation {
  0%,20%{transform: scale(1)}
  25%,45%{transform: scale(1.2)}
  50%,100%{transform: scale(1)}
}

#pants {
  position: absolute;
  left: 160px;
  top: 110px;
}

#pants .rect-pants{
  animation: pants-animation 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes pants-animation {
  0%,50%{height: 147px; y: 0px;}
  55%,75%{height: 180px; y: -14px;}
  80%,100%{height: 147px; y: 0px;}
}

#pants .g-icon{
  animation: pants-icon-animation 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes pants-icon-animation {
  0%,50%{transform: scale(1)}
  55%,75%{transform: scale(1.2)}
  80%,100%{transform: scale(1)}
}

#pants path{
  animation: pants-icon-fill 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes pants-icon-fill {
  0%,50%{fill: #DADADA;}
  55%,75%{fill: #8e8d8b;}
  80%,100%{fill: #DADADA;}
}

#mouse {
  position: absolute;
  left: 160px;
  top: 280px;
  animation: mouse-animation 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes mouse-animation {
  0%,27%{tranform:translate(0px);}
  28%,38%{transform:translate(-80px,-70px);}
  58%,68%{transform:translate(90px,-70px);}
  69%,100%{tranform:translate(0px);}
}
```

```html
<svg id="box" width="315" height="341" viewBox="0 0 315 341" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect x="10.5" y="9.5" width="304" height="331" rx="19.5" fill="#242420" stroke="#242420" />
  <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="304" height="331" rx="19.5" fill="#D9D9D9" stroke="#242420" />
  <circle cx="23" cy="20" r="6.5" fill="#C9C9C9" stroke="#242420" />
  <circle cx="47" cy="20" r="6.5" fill="#C9C9C9" stroke="#242420" />
  <circle cx="71" cy="20" r="6.5" fill="#C9C9C9" stroke="#242420" />
</svg>

<svg id="t-shirt" width="147" height="147" viewBox="0 0 147 147" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect class="rect-shirt transition" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="146" height="146" rx="19.5" fill="#EBEBEB" stroke="#242420" stroke-width="1" ></rect>
  
  <g class="g-icon g-shirt">
  <path d="M112.243 116.336H34.834L35.0547 113.12L35.2341 110.749L35.441 107.977L35.6066 105.579L35.8135 102.806L35.9928 100.408L36.1998 97.6353L36.3653 95.2648L41.1525 29.251H53.8172C53.9529 34.4014 56.0844 39.295 59.7577 42.8896C63.431 46.4841 68.3559 48.4956 73.4833 48.4956C78.6106 48.4956 83.5354 46.4841 87.2087 42.8896C90.882 39.295 93.0136 34.4014 93.1493 29.251H105.869L110.643 95.2648L110.822 97.6353L111.029 100.408L111.194 102.806L111.401 105.579L111.581 107.977L111.788 110.749L111.953 113.12L112.243 116.336Z" fill="#D9D9D9" />
  <path d="M37.7369 29.251L13.5466 58.7078L34.2872 75.6963L37.7369 29.251Z" fill="#d9d9d9" />
  <path d="M109.34 29.251L133.53 58.7078L112.776 75.6963L109.34 29.251Z" fill="#D9D9D9" />
    </g>
</svg>

<svg id="pants" width="148" height="147" viewBox="0 0 148 147" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect class="rect-pants transition" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="146" height="146" rx="19.5" fill="#EBEBEB" stroke="#242420" stroke-width="1" ></rect>  
  <g class="g-icon g-pants">
  <path d="M103.028 12.8018V19.575L74 19.5611V19.575H44.9717V12.8018H103.028Z" fill="#DADADA" />
  <path d="M94.3198 24.4131H103.028V33.1216C94.465 32.713 94.3198 24.4131 94.3198 24.4131Z" fill="#DADADA" />
  <path d="M103.028 38.4122V132.786H80.6181L74.021 45.4874L67.382 132.786H44.9717V38.4122C48.7254 37.779 57.6755 35.1361 57.6755 24.4131H71.5839C71.5839 31.7636 71.3738 38.1781 73.993 38.2607C76.6262 38.2607 76.4161 31.7636 76.4161 24.4131H90.3385C90.3245 35.1361 99.2746 37.779 103.028 38.4122Z" fill="#DADADA" />
  <path d="M44.9717 33.1216V24.4131H53.6802C53.6802 24.4131 53.5205 32.713 44.9717 33.1216Z" fill="#DADADA" />
    </g>
</svg>

<svg id="boots" width="147" height="147" viewBox="0 0 147 147" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M20.2429 0.706462H127.648C138.069 0.706462 146.516 9.15414 146.516 19.5749V126.98C146.516 137.4 138.069 145.848 127.648 145.848H20.2429C9.82217 145.848 1.37449 137.4 1.37449 126.98V19.5749C1.37449 9.15414 9.82217 0.706462 20.2429 0.706462Z" fill="#EBEBEB" stroke="#242420" stroke-width="0.967611"/>
<path d="M81.7866 41.8469C83.3104 44.2355 85.109 46.4659 87.1513 48.4994L85.747 40.902C86.6215 40.8016 87.5093 40.8922 88.3388 41.1665C89.1683 41.4408 89.9161 41.8911 90.5218 42.481C90.5218 42.481 89.6651 48.0076 91.9262 50.0395C99.4396 56.8474 117.416 66.4897 120.224 66.9944C133.453 69.4406 133.453 70.5537 133.453 70.5537C133.453 70.5537 127.527 80.7137 108.399 82.2668C108.399 82.2668 96.4061 77.465 89.7916 77.465C83.177 77.465 84.9324 89.2429 84.9324 89.2429H77.0118C77.0118 89.2429 69.9899 80.7137 69.0771 72.1715C68.1643 63.6293 70.0601 58.0381 65.7206 47.3863C65.7206 47.3863 70.8466 44.2412 75.2563 41.9504C79.666 39.6595 81.7866 41.8469 81.7866 41.8469Z" fill="#D9D9D9"/>
<path d="M56.8907 56.0847C56.2885 60.2771 56.8907 61.2445 56.8907 61.2445L60.3913 51.0151C60.3913 51.0151 64.074 54.0337 62.9678 57.2715C62.9678 57.2715 59.2011 62.2765 59.6632 65.1402C61.1895 74.7247 69.171 92.3585 71.0613 94.3192C79.981 103.594 79.2529 104.471 79.2529 104.471C79.2529 104.471 67.9107 109.257 51.6957 99.879C51.6957 99.879 45.2965 89.4045 40.0455 85.6894C34.7945 81.9743 28.4933 92.3585 28.4933 92.3585L22.1781 87.9597C22.1781 87.9597 22.1781 77.2659 27.023 69.9905C31.868 62.7151 36.3768 57.5424 39.8915 46.668H43.3081C43.3081 46.668 40.8856 50.2411 48.195 53.8143C50.8819 55.14 53.8483 55.9145 56.8907 56.0847Z" fill="#D9D9D9"/>
</svg>


<svg id="mouse" width="19" height="30" viewBox="0 0 19 30" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M1.88755 25.3335L6.68873 21.6107L9.67757 28.8303L9.86274 29.2776L10.3099 29.0921L13.5109 27.7647L13.9575 27.5795L13.7726 27.1328L10.8009 19.9528L16.9545 19.0353L17.8981 18.8946L17.227 18.2165L1.93497 2.76514L1.10729 1.92885V3.10547V24.9512V25.9385L1.88755 25.3335Z" fill="#263238" stroke="#D9D9D9" stroke-width="0.967611"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score -1):

SVG patterns (and filters) don't work like CSS's background-repeat, so what you want to do is not possible using SVG. You can't have an implicitly sized viewBox and SVG element AND have fixed size pattern elements: pattern elements will be sized in viewBox units by default.

That said, there are hacky ways to get what you want to do if you're not doing something complex. For example, you can set background-repeat: repeat on the entire SVG element, and then use a filter to paint over the area outside your shape so it looks like its filled. But yeeesh...

Answer (score -2):

aight, for the SVG border issue where it only grows down n not up, and the rounded corners get all wonky u gotta try another approach. Instead of scaling, u could adjust the 'y' attribute n 'height' of the rect element on hover to make it taller from the top down. Like this:

```
#pants-border:hover {
    y: calc(originalY - growAmount);
    height: calc(originalHeight + (2 * growAmount));
}
```

Replace originalY with the initial y value of ur rect, originalHeight with its initial height, and growAmount with how much u wanna increase the height by.

for the icon inside, if u wanna keep it uniform, u might wanna wrap it in a  tag n apply transformations to that instead of the whole SVG. This way u can control the scaling of the icon separate from the border.

Btw, if u wanna keep things responsive, consider using viewBox and percentages for width and height. Also, use CSS for ur transforms n animations instead of just scaling the path. Scaling can mess things up when u want a non-uniform transformation.

hope this helps, bruh.